# Deploy java 11 web application on App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, dockerfile, java-11

I am trying to deploy a java 11 web application on GCP App Engine. The official documentation says it supports till java 1.9 and openjdk11 is still in development phase. But the need is to deploy application with java 11 only.

I have googled a few solution which says to use Docker file for java 11 but even that is not working. The application is deployed using app.yaml file. Some useful links :-

```
1. https://hub.docker.com/r/adoptopenjdk/openjdk11/
2. https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk
3. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes
4. https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk
```

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: What you are looking for is [the Custom Runtime option](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/how-to). Basically, you provide your own Docker image, like one of the ones you linked. Right now, as you said, Java 11 is on development for regular App Engine, but you can try the Custom Runtime.

Comment: I am searching for correct customized java 11 docker image which will help me to deploy application.

Answer (score 0):

The opted solution is using custom docker image which move deployment files to deployment server and initiate app engine deployment. Once Google Cloud Platform starts supporting openjdk11 it can be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Now GCP App engine supports Java 11 runtime officially, here is the documentation link.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime

If you have any existing web app running on GCP, then here is the migration guide to Java 11 runtime environment.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/java-differences

For code samples, you can refer GCP Github repository.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java11